# Comparing nucleophilicity

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions, reactivity

We have to compare the nucleophilicity of $\ce{OH-,NH2-,CH3CH2-}$ and $\ce{CH#C^{-}}$. I managed to find out that $\ce{CH3CH2-}>\ce{NH2-}>\ce{OH-}$ and that $\ce{CH3CH2-}>\ce{CH#C-}$. But I don't know how to compare $\ce{CH#C-}$ with either $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{NH2-}$.

**My attempt:**

I know that the acidity order of the 2nd period is $\ce{CH4}<\ce{NH3}<\ce{H2O,HF}$. Now the stronger an acid is, the weaker its conjugate base will be. Therefore, the conjugate base order will be:
$$\ce{CH3-}>\ce{NH2-}>\ce{HO-}>\ce{F-}$$

We know that nucleophilicity parallels basicity along the period, therefore the nucelophilicty order will be as the basicity order:
$$\ce{CH3-}>\ce{NH2-}>\ce{HO-}$$

Now we can compare $\ce{CH3CH2-}$ with $\ce{CH3-}$.

Since methyl is an electron donating group, it will increase the negative charge on the carbanion and therefore $\ce{CH3CH2-}$ will be more nuceleophilic than $\ce{CH3-}$.

Since $\ce{CH3-}$ is more nucleophilic than $\ce{NH2-}$ and $\ce{OH-}$. Also $\ce{CH3CH2-}$ is more nuceleophilic than $\ce{CH3-}$. As a result $\ce{CH3CH2-}$ will be more nuceleophilic than $\ce{NH2-}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2-}$.

We can also compare $\ce{CH3CH2-}$ and $\ce{CH#C-}$. Since $\ce{CH#C-}$ has sp hybridization, it will be less nuceleophilic than $\ce{CH3CH2-}$.

But how can I compare $\ce{CH#C-}$ to either $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{NH2-}$?

Comment: I don't know the reason but I have acidity order as H2O >$\ce{CH#CH}$ >NH3. Hence nucleophilicity will be OH- < $\ce{CH#C^{-}}$ < NH3.

Comment: Do you have a order of nucleophilicity list? I could really use one of those.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't have any such list.

Comment: But nucleophilicity and basicity are not the same.

Comment: But nucleophilicity runs in parallel with basicity in a period

Comment: @Abhishek Maybe, but I won't take that rule of thumb too seriously. There can be subtle but significant differences between nucleophilicity and basicity. For one thing, nucleophilicity is defined in terms of kinetics and basicity in terms of equilibrium. This makes the two properties possibly respond differently to reaction conditions such as changing the temperature. My point is don't take their correlation as a stricter rule than it is.

Answer (score 2):

You also may want to consider Hard-Soft Acid-Base Theory. The carbanion is generally said to be a better nucleophile than hydroxide, presumably as measured in a highly controlled setting using a standard electrophile like methyl iodide. I'm under the impression nucleophilicity is very nearly *defined* as how fast an electron donor reacts with $\ce{CH3I}$. Note that there are no hydrogens available for elimination on this electrophile, which precludes the possibility of the nucleophile acting as a base instead.

In practical reaction conditions (protic solvents, beta-hydrogens on electrophile, etc), we may need to worry about our nucleophile acting as a base. This is where [HSAB Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory?wprov=sfla1)comes in. Hydroxide is considered a "hard base", which means it may be more inclined to react with "hard acids" like $\ce{H+}$ rather than "soft acids" like methyl iodide. As a "soft base", a carbanion will probably prefer to bond with methyl iodide (as a classic nucleophile) than with any available protons (as a Brønsted-Lowry base). So in practice, the difference between a carbanion's nucleophilicity and hydroxide's might be larger than expected due to competing "hard base" reactions (Brønsted-Lowry rather than Lewis). Just food for thought.

[Qualitative nucleophilicty ratiomale](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/06/18/what-makes-a-good-nucleophile/)

Answer (score -2):

By removing H ions, negative charge on more electronegative more stable so acidic strength order that those EN is less easily lose its electron so order of nucleophilicity EN of NH3 is 3 o is 3.5 $\ce{C#C}$ is 3.25